# How do I release multiple projects to same domain using AWS when developer commit the latest code change

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

I have multiple projects on Github and I need to release each project on same domain different paths when developer commit code changes.

Example:

I have Github repositories like below

- CRM
- CMS
- Main-Website

currently, our website is like this

- example.com/CRM
- example.com/CMS
- example.com --> is the Main-Website repository.

Please someone tell me how to do this in AWS using there services. Currently im doing this manually login to server and git pull

Thanks.

Comment: not sure this answer is what you are looking for - would e.g. Bamboo or Jenkins depoyoment routines suite your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer a few years back! and here you go :D

In AWS, we have to use Cloudfront service to archive this.

Cloudfront has origin and behaviors settings, where you can define them.

For example:

If your domain name is: example.com

You can define the path: `example.com/crm` and you can map this path with `AWS Lambda function, EB or any related service`.

Likewise you will be able to create much as you want.

- `example.com/crm` to lambda
- `example.com/blog` to EB
- `example.com/app` to S3

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to try scripting the actions you want. Then use [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to trigger your scripts to release the latest code to your environment. Alternatively, you could [use something](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs/) like Jenkins to configure a ["push on green"](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/573/what-is-push-on-green) system if you are working with compiled code. Lastly, (though I haven't used them) Amazon claims that their [CodePipeline product](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) can do this (and perhaps [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) can as well), though my personal preference is to keep things as generic as possible and avoid drinking Amazon's Kool-Aid in order to keep things portable. Like a drug dealer, the first hit may be free with Amazon, and things are great until they have you hooked and decide to jack up the price. Utilizing my own open source system ensures that I can easily take my ball and go to another cloud or home altogether (and host it myself) in the event that I need to make a rapid exit from Amazon's cloud and avoids lock-in.

Comment: This is not the answer I want, But what you told is true. :)